# Internal Sever Error 500

Tags: .htaccess, apache, rewrite

В общем, сделал Rewrite в **.htaccess**

```
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+) user.php?id=$1
```

После этого, когда перехожу на **/user/..**, данные отображаются корректно, но не загружаются скрипты, стили.
Ошибка в консоли:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

В чем может быть проблема? И где можно посмотреть более развернутый лог этой ошибки? Работаю на Ubuntu.

Comment: Причем стили, подключенные через CDN, ошибку не выдают

Comment: Пути во всех ссылках на страницах генерируйте полные: `https://examle.com/styles/mystyle.css`

Answer (score 0):

> В чем может быть проблема? И где можно посмотреть более развернутый лог этой ошибки?

Эта ошибка означает неправильную конфигурацию сервера или неверную работу веб-приложения. Найти более подробную информацию в каждом конкретном случае можно в журнале ошибок веб-сервера. В Apache под Linux он по умолчанию расположен в файле `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. Загляните туда, и скорее всего, суть проблемы сразу станет ясна. Ну а коли нет — милости просим [задать новый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) (предварительно поискав уже существующее решение, конечно же).